# How to extract data from Sentinel/Log analytics into powerbi using Azure AD Service Principal

Tags: azure, api, powerbi, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I would like to know if there's a way to extract data from Sentinel/Log analytics to powerbi using Azure AD Service Principal

I found the following video but, this will not work for me since I have multiple customers reports in one workspace

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGpfwpjlMro

Comment: You can refer to [Embed Power BI content with service principal and an application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#get-started-with-a-service-principal), [Import Azure Monitor log data into Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/powerbi) and [Ability to use Azure AD service principals to authenticate towards a data source?](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/e98lyw/ability_to_use_azure_ad_service_principals_to/)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT think this still has the workspace limitations which I mentioned earlier